# blank spaces and repetition in dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

My drop down boxes are working fine using multiples of this code which, I admit, is very rudimentary:

```
   $sql = "SELECT Country FROM engravers order by Country";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

      echo "<select name\\='Country'>";
      echo "<option value='$_POST'>Country</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Country'] . "'>" . $row['Country'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";
```

The only problem is that if I have more than one item in the field I get a response for each item, for instance, in my testing database there are two rows with Australia as the country. My dropdown then puts Australia in twice. Later, when there will be about a hundred Australian entries this will be a problem.

Also if there is a blank field I get a blank line in the drop down box. I don't seem to be able to find a solution to this. Is there a better way to write the drop down code that doesn't do this. Unfortunately, as a novice, I am using the simplest code I can understand but the results look just like that. Any help would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: That's great, thanks. All the tutorials I've worked through have been basic ones on line and they all seem to speak different languages. I think I might book a course somewhere and learn this properly.

Comment: That works perfectly. It's great to learn a new command. I have one other query. There are three fields of engraver, depending on which part of the job they did. I wanted to have a single drop down which picked up Engraver1Surname, Engraver2Surname and Engraver3Surname. In the article that I read, they simply put all three in the select line with a comma after the first two but when I tried this, I simply got a blank sheet. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, you can select multiple fields like the article suggests eg `SELECT engraver1, engraver2, engraver3 FROM engravers`. If that is not working you may want to create a new question with more details. I see you are new to StackOverflow. Welcome! You should know that comments like these should not be attached to your question, but to the answer to which they pertain. This way the poster will get notified when you post a comment or ask for clarification. Also, if an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark, and upvote when you get enough rep. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country 
FROM engravers 
WHERE Country <> ''
ORDER BY Country
```

---

`SELECT DISTINCT` will take care of multiples - if there are 100 rows with Country = Australia, it will only select one.

`WHERE Country <> ''` will exclude any rows that have a blank value for Country. You could also include `AND Country IS NOT NULL` to exclude NULL values as well.

---

*References:*

[**<> (Not equal operator)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal), [**SELECT DISTINCT ...**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)